# Multilabel classification using ResNet - loading sample using the dataloader takes a long time

Tags: pytorch, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I need to implement a ResNet-based multiclass classifier, and I am using [this notebook](https://jovian.ai/droste-benedikt/02-article-pytorch-multilabel-classification-v2) as a starting point. At the moment, I am just going through the notebook, checking that all steps work fine. When I try to load a sample with the dataloader (command: `sample = next(iter(train_loader))`), I get no results even after waiting for more than an hour. Why is that?

The dataloader is defined in this cell:

```
#Pre-processing transformations
data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224,224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5), (0.5,0.5,0.5))
    ])

#Getting the data
cardata = CarDataset("./content/content/carimages/car_ims", transform=data_transforms,translation_dict=translation_dict)

#Split the data in training and testing
train_len = int(cardata.__len__()*0.8)
test_len = int(cardata.__len__()*0.2)
train_set, val_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(cardata, [train_len, test_len])

#Create the dataloader for each dataset
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, 
                                num_workers=4, drop_last=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=16, shuffle=False, 
                               num_workers=4, drop_last=True)
```

If I try loading the data on the GPU using

```
train_set.cardata.to(torch.device("cuda:0"))  # put data into GPU entirely
train_set.to(torch.device("cuda:0"))
```

I get the error `'Subset' object has no attribute 'cardata'`. Am I doing something wrong? Is it just normal that the dataloader takes so long to load the dataset images? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no error at calling train/val set and loader of provided code. There might be an error inside of `CarDataset()` class, or maybe setting `num_workers=0` could help.

Also, please avoid acquiring a sample via `next(iter(train_loader))`. This creates a new loader every time it is called. Use `train_iter = iter(train_loader)` and `inputs, labels = train_iter.next()` instead.

Additionally, as far as I know, putting the entire dataset to a GPU or GPUs is not supported. You can load a mini-batch data (pytorch tensor) to it: `inputs = inputs.to(torch.device("cuda"))`

Any advise or correcting a wrong answer is welcomed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the tips! I made the changes you suggested and now the code runs fine. One question: what does it happen when we set `num_workers=0`? It looks like that was the missign part.

Comment: I have no accurate information about `num_workers`, but as far as I know, it sets the number of a CPU processes in a loader. According to [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/errors-when-using-num-workers-0-in-dataloader/97564), Window OS restricts multiprocessing which cause an error when `num_workers` is set > 0. Also in my experience, it sometimes causes error when it is used inside of a docker container due to the limitation of shared memory .